# VBA Run Macro Last Day of the Month

Tags: vba, excel

I want to return the last day in the month. The month is selected from a drop-down combo box. If I select January, this will return "1/31/2017" but I just want it to return 31. What am I missing?

```
EndDate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(ComboBox1.Value & Year(Date), 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `WorksheetFunction.EoMonth` returns a `Date`, while you want a numeric value representing the Day (of the last day of the month).

So you need a `Long` variable, and you can use the `Day` function.

```
EndDate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(ComboBox1.Value & Year(Date), 0)

Dim myDay As Long
myDay = Day(EndDate)
```