# VBA get the last day of the month

Tags: vba

I am  pretty new to VBA. I have a range of dates and I need to write a code that will change the date in the cell to the last day of the month, used in a cell. 
For example, if the date in the cell is `28/03/2018` I want it to be replaced by `31/03/2018`. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: I would go to the next month and then one day back... `dateserial(year("Value from the cell"),month("Value from the cell")+1,1)-1` You may not need the VBA at all, just formulas in Excel

Comment: `=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,1)-1` or `=EOMONTH(A2,0)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also get the result you need with one line of code thanks to the Eomonth formula:

```
Range("A1") = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Range("A1").Value2, 0)
```

Comment: The Application.WorksheetFunction is a nice trick. Didn't know about that.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a user-defined function `GetLastDayOfMonth()` and pass the range you are interested in:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetLastDayOfMonth(ByVal myDate As Date) As Date
    GetLastDayOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate) + 1, 0)
End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Range("A1") = DateSerial(2000, 11, 11)
    If Range("A1") = GetLastDayOfMonth(Range("A1")) Then
        Debug.Print "LAST DAY!"
    End If

    Range("A1") = DateSerial(2000, 12, 31)
    If Range("A1") = GetLastDayOfMonth(Range("A1")) Then
        Debug.Print "LAST DAY! " & Range("A1")
        Range("A1") = DateAdd("d", 1, Range("A1"))
    End If

End Sub
```

The function checks the month and the year of the date, which is passed and it returns a new date, which is the last day of the month for this specific month and year.

Then in the `TestMe` version, you can compare a given date with the last day of the month, generated by the function. If the dates are the same, then this date is the last day of the corresponding month. Using `DateAdd()` it is possible to get the next day of the lastDay.

In the example above, I have explicitly written Range("A1") 9 times, thus it is probably easier to follow.

Answer (score 6):

To get it really short you can use:

```
Sub test()

    Dim myDate As Date

    myDate = #3/28/2018#
    Debug.Print DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate) + 1, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: best answer is always the one with 0 confusion points. This one.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you just want the last day of the month in Excel, use the =EOMONTH function, or see this SO post for the vba code: 
[VBA Run Macro Last Day of the Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851672/vba-run-macro-last-day-of-the-month)

Rolling your own date time code is a bad idea. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

This VBA function will calculate the last day of the month:

```
    Public Function LastDay(ByVal d As Date)
    Dim returnDate As Date
    'First day of current month
    returnDate = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 1)
    'Forward a month
    returnDate = DateAdd("m", 1, returnDate)
    'back one day
    returnDate = DateAdd("d", -1, returnDate)
    LastDay = returnDate
End Function
```

Works by jumping to the beginning of the month, adding a month then subtracting a day  (so 1st Feb->1st Mar->28 Feb)

Answer (score 0):

#### VBA way:

```vb
Function LastDayOfMonth(ByVal d As Date)
  LastDayOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 1)
  LastDayOfMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, LastDayOfMonth)
  LastDayOfMonth = DateAdd("d", -1, LastDayOfMonth)
End Function
```

1. Construct new date:

   - **year**: from old date
   - **month**: from old date
   - **day**: 1
2. Add **1 month** to new date.
3. Subtract **1 day** from new date.

Steps **2** and **3** save you from all complexities of date calculations.

For Excel way, please refer to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642701/2392157).

Answer (score 0):

Like this in VBA:

```
Sub LastDayOfMonth()
    Dim dates As Range, dt As Range

    Set dates = Range("A1") //Update as required

    For Each dt In dates
        dt = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(dt, 0) //e.g. 01/06/2018 ~~~> 30/06/2018
    Next
End Sub
```