# VBA DateAdd() function is not adding the correct number of days to each subsequent month

Tags: excel, vba

I have a few dates within a row (ex. 4/30/2020, 5/31/2020, 6/30/2020) and am trying to add the next end of month date to each subsequent cell. Ex. after 6/30/2020, I want to add 7/31/2020 within the following column (same row). I have been able to add the correct months and years using the DateAdd fxn but the days of the months have been off. For example, all of the days are 30 when some should be 31 or 29/28. I am doing this for 3 months at a time using a code that is selecting the date of the last cell in the "date" row.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
   
    lastCol = .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    dDate = .Cells(6, lastCol).Value
   
End With

Dim y As Integer
For y = 0 To 2

Cells(6, lastCol + y).Select
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Value = DateAdd("m", 1 + y, dDate)
Selection.Font.Bold = True

Next y
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642949/1521579

Comment: try: `Selection.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(dDate ,y + 1)`

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner, that worked!